# `tail -f` consumes last line partially, doesn't care about newlines or nul

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, tail, buffer

I've got a temporary file (**not** a fifo/pipe) that needs to be watched by multiple reader scripts. Each script uses a background process to watch the temporary file, using this code:

```bash
function file_relay {
    # $1 is a regular file to read from
    local bg_file
    bg_file="$1"

    # $2 is a fifo to relay to
    local outfile
    outfile="$2"

    tail -f "$bg_file" | while read -r line
    do
        [[ ! -z "$line" ]] && { printf "%s" "$line" >>"$outfile"; }
    done
}
```

They need to read the entire file when they start, then watch for new lines, which the above function does:

```bash
file_relay /tmp/examplefile /tmp/examplefifo &
```

Each script will output lines to this file as well. So it's a multiple-writer and multiple-reader situation.

The problem is that sometimes `tail -f` doesn't wait for a full line to be available, even though I'm using `printf` to redirect to the file and I've got newlines at the end of the strings. This causes the lines read to be corrupted, with the first word of the last line being appended at the end of the previous one, so I get:

```
This is one lineThis
```

instead of

```
This is one line
This is another line
```

I've tried to work around `printf`'s buffering, `tail -f`'s buffering as well as use `sync` around writes to the file (the file is read only in the function above and I don't know how to force `tail` to run `sync` before attempting to read the entire line). `stdbuf` doesn't seem to have any effect anywhere, nor does using `-z` for `tail`, or terminating strings with `$'\0'` or anything else. The only thing that prevents it from happening right away is a single `sync` before the `while` loop starts, but that doesn't prevent it from happening after that.

**Is there any way to force `tail -f` to read only complete lines?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short: not directly

long: it's not portable (not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html)), but if you limit your interest to Linux, you can pipe the *output* of `tail -f` through something which *is* line-buffered.  For instance, as suggested in *[unix command 'tail' lost option '--line-buffered'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227308/unix-command-tail-lost-option-line-buffered)*, GNU grep has a `--line-buffered` option, allowing you to do this

```
tail -f "$bg_file" | grep --line-buffered -E '^.*$'
```

However as the [manual](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/grep1.html) points out

> **`--line-buffered`**
>   Use line buffering, ***it can be a performance penality***.

([FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&sektion=&n=1) has the same option and comment from [OpenBSD in 2004](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/grep/grep.c?rev=1.27&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup), not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) yet...).

The documentation doesn't point this out, but the [initial commit in 2001](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/src/grep.c?id=1236f00774c60964d9c1661e7a8f6833d45596f5) had in mind the time spent doing `fflush`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try it out if I move back to this way of doing things (already implemented a background message broker using a FIFO).